# Homeomorphism of Klein Bottle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, klein-bottle

Proof that the Klein bottle is homeomorphic to $T/S$ where $T$ is the torus of revolution and $S$ is the equivalence relation given by $(x, y, z) \sim (x', y', z')$ if and only if $(x, y, z) = \pm (x', y', z')$.
How do I must do it? Sorry, I am new in this.

Comment: How, more precisely, is $T$ defined? Something like the circle $(x-2)^2+z^2=1$ in the $x,z$ plane revolved around the $z$ axis? And which one of many equivalent definitions of the Klein bottle have you been given? There are many ways to do this, but which one to choose depends on such details.

Comment: T is the torus and the Klein bottle, for me, is the quotient space described as the square [0,1] × [0,1] with sides identified by the relations (0, y) ~ (1, y) for 0 ≤ y ≤ 1 and (x, 0) ~ (1 − x, 1) for 0 ≤ x ≤ 1.

Comment: Please go easy on the editing, @azimut, 3 or 4 a day, not 20 or 30 an hour. You are flooding the front page with old questions.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the equivalence relation is a reflection through the origin, you can view the quotient by cutting the torus in half along a plane (say, $x = 0$), and gluing the boundary appropriately together. Since this half-torus is just a cylinder, you should be able to reasonably either draw a picture, or relate this to the usual description of the Klein bottle for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I could use this lemma:
Suppose X is a topological space, ∼ an equivalence relation on X, and Q = X/ ∼ the quotient space (i.e. the set of equivalence classes, with the quotient topology). Suppose Y is a space and f : X → Y is a continuous surjective map such that the equivalence classes in X are precisely the point-inverses under f; that is,foreachx,y ∈ X,x∼y ⇐⇒ f(x)=f(y). If X is compact and Y is Hausdorff, then X/ ∼ is homeomorphic to Y . Right?